# which header file contains ThrowIfFailed() in DirectX 12

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, directx-12

[some part of code image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnJ6H.png) [another part of code image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQhHJ.png) I am beginner to *DirectX 12* (or Game Programming) and studying from Microsoft documentation. While using function `ThrowIfFailed()` I get an error from intellisense of *vs2015* editor

> This declaration has no storage class or type specifier.

Can anyone help.

Comment: It's not a header issue. You simply write code outside of any function

Comment: Please post your code to help us to see what's happen

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn859356(v=vs.85).aspx   Its written inside LoadPipeline() funtion

Comment: Ok, so, what is _your_ code

Comment: I have written the same

Comment: Probably not exactly same. If it was the case, you will probably have no error

Comment: Sorry sir, But I am not getting how to give code in Stackoverflow

Comment: Sir I have given code images, please check that...

Comment: It's really hard to help you with image... Please copy/paste, or use a external service to have TEXT. And you didn't have same code as MS. And `ThrowIfFailed` is outside of function as I already said. See my answer

Comment: For future : read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [minimal compilable and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) And to post code see [Markdown editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Is my answer solved your issue ? If so, please accept it

Comment: Yes, it corrected that issue but it is now showing "Identifier ThrowIfFailed is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **As you are new to DirectX programming, I *strongly* recommend starting with DirectX 11 rather than DirectX 12.** DirectX 12 assumes you are already an expert DirectX 11 developer, and is a quite unforgiving API. It's absolutely worth learning if you plan to be a graphics developer, but starting with DX 12 over DX 11 is a huge undertaking. See the *DirectX Tool Kit* tutorials for [DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and/or [DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started)

For modern DirectX sample code and in the VS DirectX templates, Microsoft uses a standard helper function `ThrowIfFailed`. It's not part of the OS or system headers; it's just defined in the local project's Precompiled Header File (`pch.h`):

```
#include <exception>

namespace DX
{
    inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
    {
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // Set a breakpoint on this line to catch DirectX API errors
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }
}
```

For COM programming, you must check at runtime all `HRESULT` values for failure. If it's safe to ignore the return value of a particular DirectX 11 or DirectX 12 API, it will return `void` instead. You generally use `ThrowIfFailed` for 'fast fail' scenarios (i.e. your program can't recover if the function fails).

> Note the recommendation is to use [C++ Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t3saedz.aspx) (a.k.a. `/EHsc`) which is the default compiler setting in the VS templates. On the x64 and ARM platforms, this is implemented very efficiently without any additional code overhead. Legacy x86 requires some additional epilog/prologue code that the compiler creates. Most of the "FUD" around exception handling in native code is based on the experience of using the older Asynchronous Structured Exception Handling (a.k.a. `/EHa`) which severely hampers the code optimizer.

See [this wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) for a bit more detail and usage information. You should also read the page on [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

In my version of the Direct3D Game VS Templates on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates), I use a slightly enhanced version of `ThrowIfFailed` which you could also use:

```
#include <exception>

namespace DX
{
    // Helper class for COM exceptions
    class com_exception : public std::exception
    {
    public:
        com_exception(HRESULT hr) : result(hr) {}

        virtual const char* what() const override
        {
            static char s_str[64] = {};
            sprintf_s(s_str, "Failure with HRESULT of %08X",
                static_cast<unsigned int>(result));
            return s_str;
        }

    private:
        HRESULT result;
    };

    // Helper utility converts D3D API failures into exceptions.
    inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
    {
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            throw com_exception(hr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, do you recommend any book for DirectX11 or github is enough ?

Comment: @ShivamKushwaha You can find lots of tutorials on the internet

Answer (score 0):

This error is because some of your code are outside of any function.

Your error is just here :

```
void D3D12HelloTriangle::LoadPipeline() {
#if defined(_DEBUG) { //<= this brack is simply ignore because on a pre-processor line

        ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugController;
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugController)))) {
            debugController->EnableDebugLayer();
        }
    } // So, this one closes method LoadPipeline
#endif

// From here, you are out of any function
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> factory;
ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory)));
```

So to correct it :

```
void D3D12HelloTriangle::LoadPipeline() {
#if defined(_DEBUG) 
    { //<= just put this bracket on it's own line

        ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugController;
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugController)))) {
            debugController->EnableDebugLayer();
        }
    } // So, this one close method LoadPipeline
#endif

// From here, you are out of any function
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> factory;
ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory)));
```