# Undefined identifiers - which header files are missing? - DX12

Tags: c++, directx, header-files

I am trying to play with the new DX12 API and I have found and copied some code from the Microsoft Documentations regarding it but after copying the code many functions are still being unidentified.

I have been searching the documentations in detail but I am unable to find the right headers for them. Headers that I have included are the following:

```
#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from 
#include "windows.h"
// C RunTime Header Files
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "memory.h"
#include "tchar.h"
//for wstrings
#include "locale"
//for Microsoft namespace
#include "collection.h"
//for SwapChain3
#include "dxgi1_4.h"
#include "D3DX12.h"
#include "D3d12.h"
#include "directxmath.h"
#include "D3DCompiler.h"
```

The unidentified functions and properties are:
ThrowIfFailed, GetHardwareAdapter, Win32Application namespace and GetAssetFullPath

Comment: ThrowIfFailed() is not part of the system include files. It has just defined in some recompiled header files.

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789396/which-header-file-contains-throwiffailed-in-directx-12

Comment: The ``collection.h`` header is specific to [Windows Runtime C++/CX extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/collections-c-cx) and UWP , so you shouldn't be using it in a Win32 desktop app generally speaking. Also: Die, ``tchar.h``! Die! See [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: DirectXMath is part of the Windows 10 SDK, but you can also find the latest version on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are 'helpers' included in various starter templates and samples, but are not part of the actual Windows APIs in the Windows SDK. In particular, you will see them in the samples from the official DirectX 12 Samples [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld) for Win32 desktop.

- `ThrowIfFailed` is a simple "if COM returned a failure, throw a C++ exception" helper. This is because you should always check the return value of any COM function that returns `HRESULT` instead of `void`, but in 'working' programs most of the time any failure code from Direct3D in many places is a 'fast-fatal' error. The 'official' desktop samples for DX12 define it in [DXSampleHelper.h](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloWindow/DXSampleHelper.h), but many other templates put it into the `pch.h` precompiled header to make sure it's defined globally. See [this wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) for more details.
- `GetHardwareAdapter` is another helper. When you [create a DirectX 11 device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) on any modern versions of Windows, you can pretty safely assume there's some Direct3D adapter there depending on your minimum [Direct3D Hardware Feature level](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-feature-levels/). With DirectX 12, you really need to check as it's quite possible that you have both a DX11 and a DX12 capable device on your system. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/) for more details on creating a DirectX 12 device.
- The `Win32Application` namespace is just a really simple WndProc and window helper. You can see the implementation here [cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloWindow/Win32Application.cpp) / [h](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloWindow/Win32Application.h)
- `GetAssetFullPath` is another helper, but this one is more specific to the 'official' DirectX 12 samples. It basically deals with the fact that when doing development in Visual Studio, the 'current working directory' is typically the project folder, but the various shader blobs (`cso` files) built by Visual Studio are found next to the `EXE` in *Debug*, *Release*, etc. You can find it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloWindow/DXSampleHelper.h).

> This is a 'quirk' of Win32 desktop development since there's no standard packaging/setup/deployment system. For UWP and Xbox One development, the packaging typically places the `EXE` and `CSO` files next to each other along with other assets, and the Current Working Directory is set to the root of the 'package' at runtime.
>
> Personally, I deal with the same issue slightly differently in my [ReadData](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/microsoft/DirectXTK/ReadData.h) helper.

Another common issue is that the various `D3DX12*` helper functions are also *not* part of the Windows SDK. Instead you get `D3DX12.H` as part of a DirectX project template or from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Libraries/D3DX12). The documentation is on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/helper-structures-and-functions-for-d3d12).

> I have a set of DirectX basic templates for Visual C++ hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki) you might want to look at. They include the [DeviceResources](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/DeviceResources) module for handling your basic DirectX device when you are just getting started, the [StepTimer](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/StepTimer) helper, as well as `D3DX12.h`.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/getting-started-with-direct3d-12/) and [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) for some general tips.

> If you are really new to DirectX, you should seriously consider working with [DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-started) before tackling DirectX 12.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am new to DirectX 12, but I have been studying DIrectX 11 and I was asking for a hard project for my final year because I want my degree to actually have an impact. I know it's going to be a big task but I am up for it. Thank you once again, I really appreciate your time and shared knowledge!